# Select polygons with other polygons layer?

Tags: qgis, polygon, select-by-location

I have to select some polygons with another polygon layer. I have to select green polygons using relevant overlapping percentage with the purple ones. In this particular example, I would like to select all green polygons except the third one from starting from above for example.

Do you have any advice to do that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by superposition is adequate?

Comment: I meant something like 'relevant'. Like the answer below, I needed to deal with percentage of overlapping. Sorry for having been unclear. Thanks underdak for the clarification. I will pay extra attention next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how best we can define "adequate". But assuming over 50% of the green polygon is overlapping with purple:

1. Go to `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`
2. [Import] (**greens** and **purples**) layers

An example of query is:

```
SELECT greens.*   FROM greens, purples
WHERE st_area(st_intersection(greens.geometry, purples.geometry)) 
      > 0.5 * st_area(greens.geometry)
```

If you need a higher threshold e.g. 'at least 60% of green polygon has to overlap with purple' then change `0.5` to `0.6`.

---

If you want to decide it by the greens' centroids' location.

```
SELECT greens.*   FROM greens, purples
WHERE st_within(st_centroid(greens.geometry), purples.geometry) = 1
```

Comment: If it is the centroid, then there is a plugin for that: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SelectWithin/

Comment: Thanks @HeikkiVesanto I agree it is another possibility... just added to include `centroid` option. Yes, I appreciate the plugin, too.

Comment: I am glad @francois. By the way, if you add that information to your question (using **edit**) it will be reopened.