# QGIS: alternative to add/edit virtual layer. With python?

Tags: qgis, python, select-by-location, virtual-layer

Following a previous question ([Select polygons with other polygons layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262794/select-polygons-with-other-polygons-layer)), I select some polygons using the query in the answer to create a virtual layer:

```
SELECT greens.*  FROM greens, purples
WHERE st_area(st_intersection(greens.geometry, purples.geometry)) 
      > 0.5 * st_area(greens.geometry)
```

It works really well, but my layers contain 1.800.000 (and sometimes more) polygons. So that QGIS freezes and virtual layers only appears few days later. When I am trying to record it, it takes again several days to do that. Since I have to do the operation on several layers, it takes an incredible amount of time (that I do not have). Does someone know an alternative to use that kind of query in an other way to select the right polygons?

Comment: What do you mean by "select the right polygons"?  Is the query not producing correct results?

Comment: I meant selecting the polygons with more than 50% overlapping for example. But I think I have found the solution elsewhere: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195373/programmatically-finding-polygons-which-are-90-overlapped-by-another-vector-po/195376)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was thinking how to formulate the question, I thought a different way to look for in already-existing answers: I found a solution here: 
[Programmatically finding polygons which are >90% overlapped by another vector polygon layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195373/programmatically-finding-polygons-which-are-90-overlapped-by-another-vector-po/195376)